# Oozie work flow error

Tags: oozie

I am trying to write a simple Oozie workflow to execute a simple hive script. The hive script is executing fine without any issue, but getting issue with work flow execution.

The workflow.xml is as below:

```html
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="nielsen_dma_xref_intr_dly_load_wf">

<credentials>
<credential name="hive2_cred" type="hive2">
<property>
<name>hive2.jdbc.url</name>
<value>${hive2_jdbc_uri}</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive2.server.principal</name>
<value>${hive2_server_principal}</value>
</property>
</credential>
</credentials>

<start to="nielsen_dma_xref_intr_dly_load_wf_start"/>    

<action name="hive_load_nielsen_dma_xref_oozie" cred='hive2_cred'>
<hive2 xmlns="uri:oozie:hive2-action:0.1">
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<job-xml>${hiveSiteXML}</job-xml>
<jdbc-url>${jdbc_hive}</jdbc-url>
<password>${password}</password>
<script>${scripts}/nielsen_dma_xref_load.hql</script>
<param>db_dbname_dbname=${db_dbname}</param>
</hive2>
<ok to="hive_load_nielsen_dma_xref_oozie"/>
<error to="fail"/>
</action>

<kill name="fail">
<message>Workflow failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>

<end name="nielsen_dma_xref_intr_dly_load_wf_completed"/>

</workflow-app>
```

All files are placed under **`/user/kchandr2/wf`** folder in HDFS

I am executing the wrokflow using the command **`oozie job -oozie http://<<hostname>>:11000/oozie -config /home/kchandr2/wf/nielsen_dma_xref_intr_dly_load_wf.properties -run -verbose >> /home/kchandr2/wf/Logs/nielsen_dma_xref_intr_dly_load_wf_$(date '+%Y%m%d').log 2>&1`** where the properties file is placed in the local directory **`/home/kchandr2/wf`**

I am getting the **`Error: E0706 : E0706: Node cannot transition to itself node [hive_load_nielsen_dma_xref_oozie]`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hive2 action

```
<action name="hive_load_nielsen_dma_xref_oozie" cred='hive2_cred'>
```

you have an "ok" transition to the very same action node

```
<ok to="hive_load_nielsen_dma_xref_oozie"/>
```

This is not allowed. That's why you get the error:

```
Error: E0706 : E0706: Node cannot transition to itself node [hive_load_nielsen_dma_xref_oozie]
```

Oozie Workflows are DAGs (Direct Acyclic Graph). You cannot have loops.